# Excel VBA procedure hang when getting page's source

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to scrape some information from a couple of websites, however one in particular is causing Excel to freeze when setting an HTML document element's innerHTML to the response text. Here's the relevant part of the code I'm using with the website I'm trying to use

```
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim tbl As Object, obj_tbl As Object
Dim TR As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

url = "https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/adp/overall.php"

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
Set obj_tbl = html.getelementsbytagname("table")
```

From stepping through in the debugger, it doesn't seem to make it past the second to last line for some reason. Excel will simply lock up, be completely unresponsive (but doesn't go into not responding mode) and I have to manually end the task in the task manager. The error reporting just says AppHangB1. It works for other sites as well so I'm not sure what's going on, could use any help

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete. You need to call the `open` method and then the `send` method on the XMLHTTP object for things to work. As you say your code works for other sites, I presume you actually have those lines in your code but forgot to include them here. Please add those lines into the question

Comment: @barrowc you're right sorry, don't know how they didn't make it over. Fixed!

Comment: I'm not sure if you've solved it but I suggest you split the line into two: `sResponse = XMLHTTP.responseText` and `html.body.innerHTML = sResponse`. This will at least let you narrow it down to the read or the write as the issue

Comment: it is the assignment into innerHTML....  don't name your object XMLHTTP. why would you do that and add confusion into your code?  it's like working with two guys who are both named Bob.